# Add text under markers in mapbox ios

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox SDK in my iOS app (using Swift).
I want a label to show under every marker like this:

[image]

I couldn't find anywhere in the docs or on stackoverflow how I can achieve that. I tried to make the text a part of the marker image, but the text does not resize itself that way and things are a mess when markers are close (or when you zoom out).

Does anybody know how I can make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you'll want to do this at [the GL style level](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/) using [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) — not as dynamic annotations.

Doing it in the style allows labels to be recalculated and customized based on the surrounding data and map state, whereas annotations currently aren't as customizable.